# Execute large sql script file having stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-scripts

I have a large (1.2GB) sql(server) script file which includes lots of stored procedures. I want to execute this large file. The first problem is I cannot open the file in SQL Server Management Studio. So, I tried the following code:

```
declare @FileName  varchar(255)
declare @SQLLoad   nvarchar(max)

-- Set the file to load SQL Script from
set @FileName = 'C:\ZarifBarDB.sql'

-- Create command to load and execute the file
set @SQLLoad =
N'declare @cmd varchar(max);
select @cmd = fd.col1
from openrowset(bulk ' + QUOTENAME(@FileName, '''') + ', SINGLE_NCLOB) as FD(col1);
exec (@cmd)'

-- Load file data and execute
exec (@SQLLoad)
```

I should delete all the "GO" statements in order to execute this query. But in this way, when execution reaches the "Create Procedure" commands, I get the following error:

```
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try [sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.105).aspx) utility?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. sqlcmd gives me the following error: HResult 0xE9, Level 16, State 1 Shared memory Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe.

Comment: Use command line: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572(v=sql.110).aspx